# Not showing all records in After Insert trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table `table1` with some data:

```
create table table1
(
     c1 varchar(20),
     c2 varchar(20)
)

insert into table1 values('1','A')
insert into table1 values('2','B')
insert into table1 values('3','C')
insert into table1 values('4','D')
insert into table1 values('5','E')
insert into table1 values('6','F')
```

Now I created another table with the same structure called `table2` :

```
create table table2
(
    c1 varchar(20),
    c2 varchar(20)
)
```

Then I created an `After Insert` trigger on `table2` :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert 
ON [dbo].[table2] 
FOR INSERT
AS
    declare @c1 varchar(20);
    declare @c2 varchar(20);
    declare @audit_action varchar(100);

    select @c1 = i.c1 from inserted i;  
    select @c2 = i.c2 from inserted i;  

    set @audit_action = 'Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.';

    insert into table2_Audit(c1, c2, Audit_Action, Audit_Timestamp) 
    values(@c1, @c2, @audit_action, getdate());

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
    GO
```

There is a problem that when i copy all data of `table1` to `tabe2` then in Audit table only one record show.It not show all inserted record.

I use this query for copy the record in `table2`:-

```
  insert into table2(c1,c2) select c1,c2 from table1
```

Comment: This is perfectly normal. Trigger fire once for entire operation `insert into table2(c1,c2) select c1,c2 from table1` not for every row. Use inside trigger `insert into table2_Audit             (c1,c2,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
          SELECT cols...
         FROM inserted;`

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @c1 = i.c1 from inserted i;  ` - it's non-deterministic, you get *one, arbitrary* row and all 24 others are **ignored**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger fires once for each insert statement issued against this table. not one for each row inserted in the table. Hence if more than one row is inserted you trigger definition should be able to handle more than one row.

Instead of using variables to capture values from inserted table and then insert them in table two, simply select from the inserted table and insert the data into Table2_audit.

A trigger to handle this would look something like........

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[table2] 
        FOR INSERT
        AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into table2_Audit (c1,c2,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
    SELECT C1 
         , C2 
         , 'Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.' 
         , GETDATE() 
   FROM inserted ;

PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Trigger is fired once per entire operation, change your code to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[table2] 
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @audit_action VARCHAR(100) = 'Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.';

INSERT INTO table2_Audit(c1,c2,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
SELECT i.c1, i.c2, @audit_action, GETDATE()
FROM inserted i;

END
```

Second don't use `PRINT` inside trigger;

[More info](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/465428/insert-trigger-only-fires-once-for-multiple-row-insertion-syntax-of-values)

> The behavior you are seeing is by design. DML triggers in SQL Server
>   are statement level triggers - **they are fired once after
>   INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE irrespective of how many rows are affected
>   by the DML statement**. So you should write your logic in the trigger to
>   handle multiple rows in the inserted/deleted tables